# prevent other apps from sending broadcasts to my broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-security

I have a `broadcastReceiver` registered in manifest that receives broadcasts sent from one of my services with a custom action. I have it already working but for security reasons i want to prevent other apps from sending fake broadcast to my receiver. How can i do that?

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MyAction"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every reciever with `exported` tag set to `false` will only receive broadcasts sent from its own application process.

so it will be:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
          android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MyAction"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

As another solution i found that i can use `permissions`.

more on [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#restrict-broadcasts-permissions)

Comment: ur link doesn't lead to a valid post.